# Toggling menus based on an ID

Tags: javascript, performance

I have recently started using browserify and have created a custom module to toggle two menus based on the ID clicked and apply a transparent overlay effect behind the menu. I have got it working but just wanted to get some feedback on weather it can improved performance or coding wise as I am wanting to improve my JS skills.

```
/**
* Require modules
*/
var dullBackground = require('./dullBackground');

/**
* Export module
*/
module.exports = function() {

  'use strict';

  /**
  * Selectors
  */
  var menu = document.getElementById('nav-main');
  var panel = document.getElementById('overlay-panel');
  var productsPanel = document.getElementById('products-panel');
  var systemsPanel = document.getElementById('systems-panel');
  var close = document.getElementById('overlay-close');
  var activeClass = 'active';
  var hideClass = 'hide';

  /**
  * Methods
  */
  function togglePanel(event) {

    // Selectors
    var elementId = event.target.id;

    event.preventDefault();

    // Conditions
    if(elementId === 'page-products' || elementId === 'page-systems') {
      dullBackground();
      panel.classList.add(activeClass);
    }
    if(elementId === 'page-products') {
      productsPanel.classList.remove(hideClass);
    }
    if(elementId === 'page-systems') {
      systemsPanel.classList.remove(hideClass);
    }

  }
  function closePanel(event) {

    // Actions
    panel.classList.remove(activeClass);
    event.preventDefault();

    // Conditions
    if(!productsPanel.classList.contains(hideClass)) {
      productsPanel.classList.add(hideClass);
    }
    if(!systemsPanel.classList.contains(hideClass)) {
      systemsPanel.classList.add(hideClass);
    }

  }

  /**
  * Events/APIs/init
  */
  menu.addEventListener('click', togglePanel, false);
  close.addEventListener('click', closePanel, false);

};
```

Comment: Any chance you could share some HTML for the page? I'm trying to visualize this, but having a hard time doing so.

Comment: Not at the moment, working locally. Basically if a main mav menu item as the ID page-products or page-systems it disabled the default link action and instead displays a lightbox type overlay panel with either a list of products or systems.

Answer (score 2):

First time doing a review, so bear with me.

I've been thinking about how to make any changes to your code, but had a difficult time finding things that could be optimized. Overall, I think you did a great job.

Selectors - this may be a style preference, but I tend to lump everything under one var statement (delimited by commas), rather than having to write var each time.

Methods - I chose to pass the `elementId` into `document.getElementById` rather than having to write additional if statements to check specifically for either `id`. You're already checking to see what `event.target.id` is returning, might as well use it again.

Methods - `closePanel`, I created a function called `checkClassListAndAddClass` very long, but at least you know what it's doing. This function takes the selector as an argument, checks to see if the selector contains a class, and then returns the add class. I added a variable to that function to help remove some repetitive code.

Again, this is my first stab at a code review, so I'm happy to hear your feedback as well as any other feedback from the community.

```
/**
* Require modules
*/
var dullBackground = require('./dullBackground');

module.exports = function () {

    'use strict';

    /**
    * Selectors
    */
    var menu = document.getElementById('nav-main'),
        overlay = document.getElementById('overlay-panel'),
        close = document.getElementById('overlay-close'),
        productsPanel = document.getElementById('page-products'),
        systemsPanel = document.getElementById('page-systems'),
        activeClass = 'active',
        hideClass = 'hide';

    /**
    * Methods
    */
    function togglePanel(event) {
        var elementId = event.target.id;

        event.preventDefault();

        if (elementId === ('page-products' || elementId === 'page-systems')) {
            dullBackground();
            overlay.classList.add(activeClass);
            document.getElementById(elementId).classList.remove(hideClass);
        }
    }

    function closePanel(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        overlay.classList.remove(activeClass);

        checkClassListAndAddClass(productsPanel);
        checkClassListAndAddClass(systemsPanel);
    }

    function checkClassListAndAddClass(selector) {
        var selClassList = selector.classList;

        if (!selClassList.contains(hideClass)) {
            return selClassList.add(hideClass);
        }
    }

    /**
    * Events/APIs/init
    */
    menu.addEventListener('click', togglePanel, false);
    close.addEventListener('click', closePanel, false);

};
```